# css td overflow with spans having variable length

Tags: css

I have a table with two columns. The width of the 2 columns are set and should not be modified. The first column contains 2 spans standing side by side. The content of the first span has a variable length. The second span also. What I would like to do is to hide the overflow of the second span when the content hits the border. I tried several things but I do not manage to find a solution. Hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

http://cssdesk.com/eAN3d

My HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>th1</th>
    <th>th2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Paul</span>
      <span class="hide-overflow">Some text with no overflow</span>
    </td>
    <td>txt</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Emmanuelle</span>
      <span class="hide-overflow">The overflow of this text string has to be hidden.The td has to be only one line and the width should not be extended.</span>
    </td>
    <td>txt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
table{
  width:400px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;}

th,td{
  border:1px solid black;}

td:first-child{
  width:350px;}

td:last-child{
  width:50px;}

.hide-overflow{
  background-color:yellow;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not incredibly happy with this, but it does seem to work in Firefox. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rEj6p/1/)

```
table{
  width:400px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout:fixed;
}

th,td {
  border:1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th:first-child, td:first-child{
  width:350px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

th:last-child, td:last-child{
  width:50px;
}

.hide-overflow{
  background-color:yellow;
}

span.hide-overflow {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

This is the result:

[image: Example]

Comment: Hello Interrobang. Unfortunately this is not helping. The width of the column is expanding without hiding the overflow. Thank you anyway for trying to help. Cheers...

Comment: What browser are you testing in? I'll pop open a VM and look.

Comment: Also, to clarify-- did you ensure to replace all your CSS? I changed properties in table, td:first-child, and span.hide-overflow.

Comment: So far I've confirmed my code works in IE9, Firefox, and Chrome. Please elaborate on which browser you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much Interrobang. It is working like a charm! You rock !!! Thanks... Will it work with below IE9?

Comment: I would imagine so, none of these properties are CSS3. Please upvote and accept helpful answers as relevant. Cheers!